# How to send string to servlet from my java class

Tags: java, servlets

Client.java 
sending string into servlet

```
    String url = "http://localhost:8084/Lab/url";

    URL obj = new URL(url);
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

    // optional default is GET
    con.setRequestMethod("GET");
            con.setDoInput(true);
            con.setDoOutput(true);
            dos = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
            dos.writeBytes(resultJson.toString());
    int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                                con.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
                System.out.println(inputLine);

            dos.flush();
            dos.close();
            in.close();
```

Servlet
getting values from client and return

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
```

I dont know what to do next.

Comment: which string you want to pass?

Comment: With `GET` you pass parameters in the URL, perhaps you need to use `POST`?

Comment: @JqueryLearner like this {"lol":5,"lolid":[1,2,3,4,5]}

Comment: you can pass parameters with your url if you are using GET method.

See [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) for more reference

Comment: @olle Is your client.java a servlet?

Comment: @JqueryLearner no, it simple run class

Comment: @olle Though I am not experinced in web service but I think use of web servie may solve your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

1. To pass string as parameter, replace **`String url = "[http://localhost:8084/Lab/url]";`** with **`String url = "[http://localhost:8084/Lab/url?str=YOURSTRING]";`**
2. In servlet, to retrieve message add: **String messsage = request.getParameter("str");**

In [1] using **GET** we are passing "str" parameter in the URL which contains our string.
We retrieve the message using `getParameter()` in servlet [2].

As @Anders said we can also do it using **POST**

I hope this is helpful.

Cheers

PS: URLS are w/o []

**[UPDATE]**

Passing parameter using POST

```
    String param = "str=YOURSTRING";
    String request = "http://localhost:8084/";
    URL url = new URL(request);
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)
    url.openConnection();          
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    connection.setDoInput(true);
    connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
    connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    connection.setRequestProperty("charset", "utf-8");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "" +  Integer.toString(param.getBytes().length));
    connection.setUseCaches (false);

    DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream ());
    out.writeBytes(param);
    out.flush();
    out.close();
    connection.disconnect();
```

Comment: If you are passing parameters in the URL then get method is used,can you describe how to use post in the same case

Comment: To do a POST with HttpURLConnection, We write the parameters to the connection after you have opened the connection.

Comment: I am referring to your answer *[http://localhost:8084/Lab/url?str=YOURSTRING]";* and here you said *As @Anders said we can also do it using POST* your gave answer for get but not for post.Update your answer for post also so that it will be helpful for users to understand more

Comment: ^ I have updated my answer (on how to pass parameter using POST)